# A faster method for computing conjugation classes

Tags: group-theory

I am asked to find the conjugation classes of a group order n. I am aware what a conjugation class is and how to find it. My question: is there a quicker/more simple way to find the conjugation classes of the group oppose to manually conjugating by each element of the group?

Comment: It may depend on the specifics of the group. Things get somewhat easier if one has a nice *action* of the group on some set at hand.

Comment: To find all the conjugates of $x$ you only need to conjugate is by representatives of cosets of the centralizer of $x$. Observe that the subgroup generated by $x$ itself obviously centralizes it. At first this is time-consuming, but doing it for a few small groups is good practice. How large is your $n$?

Comment: Depends on how your group is given, what else you know about the group, etc.. This question would be better if you had a specific example in mind

Comment: If your group is given as a group of permutations, then you can use that fact that conjugate permutations have the same cycle structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general thing you can do for finite groups is think about the class equation,
$$
|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_x [G:C_G(x)],
$$
where the sum runs over representatives of each conjugacy class.

This in and of itself is not helpful; if you already knew all the conjugacy classes well enough to find representatives, you'd be done.  However, there are a few things we can garner from this that may be helpful.

- We do know $|G|$.
- We know that each of the $[G:C_G(x)]$ must be numbers that divide $|G|$, as is $|Z(G)|$ (which you can sometimes narrow down even further if, for example, the group is nilpotent). Depending on how big $|G|$ is, there may not be too many ways for it to be a sum of its divisors.  For most numbers small enough that you'd consider computing conjugacy classes by hand, you can write out all possibilities yourself.
- Every element of $G$ that is conjugate to $x$ has the same order as $x$. Therefore, if you know the orders of each element (or even just some of them), you can narrow down which elements even *could* be in the same classes, and therefore try to match partition them up into reasonable guesses before you do any checking.  In this way you can avoid checking a lot of conjugations in many cases.

These won't take you all the way.  In general, you'll still have to conjugate a lot of stuff around, but the cuts can make it shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I was aware of all the bullet points except the last.